# What is this kotlin feature?: Kotlin extension properties as parameter type: `fun X.func(X.() -> Unit)`

Tags: android, android-fragments

I understand kotlin extension functions and kotlin extension properties. In all cases of extensions I understand, the property/ function is defined first. This seems to behave differently, where body is **implicitly assigned** as a property of `FragmentTransaction` in the function signature:

I was reading `FragmentManager.kt`:

```kotlin
inline fun FragmentManager.commit(
    allowStateLoss: Boolean = false,
    body: FragmentTransaction.() -> Unit
) {
    val transaction = beginTransaction() // of type FragmentTransaction
    transaction.body()
    if (allowStateLoss) {
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    } else {
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Otherwise, we wouldn't have been able to just call `transaction.body()`. `FragmentTransaction` class does not contain a body function/ property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called [function types with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types):

> Function types can optionally have an additional receiver type, which is specified before a dot in the notation: the type `A.(B) -> C` represents functions that can be called on a receiver object of `A` with a parameter of `B` and return a value of `C`. [Function literals with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) are often used along with these types.

So the syntax `body: FragmentTransaction.() -> Unit` means: `body` must be a method on `FragmentTransaction` that takes no arguments and returns no value. This is why we can call it as `transaction.body()`.

Apart from runtime polymorphism, methods aren't really that much different from free functions; only the call syntax differs (`object.method()` instead of `method(object)`). Maybe that helps you make sense of things.

And as indicated in the documentation, one way to create such a method is a [function literal with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver). This is just like any other function literal (lambda), except that the receiver is available as `this` inside the function, and methods of `this` are implicitly in scope inside the function definition.

Comment: Thanks for telling me what it is. The second link is helpful, but this knowledge is not flowing in 

Answer (score 0):

*This is my interpretation so far thanks to [@Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65898504/7365866) and reading the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) multiple times:*

The only reason to use "function types with receiver" is to change the `this` keyword inside the body lambda block when it gets called. It kind of makes sense, once I realize how [FragmentManager.commit](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#setReorderingAllowed(boolean)) is used anyway. It does not set `this` in body to `FragmentManager`, but to `FragmentTransaction` instead.

```kotlin
fragmentManager.commit {
    setReorderingAllowed(true) // <-- `this` belongs to FragmentTransaction
}
```

It gets `this` (FragmentTransaction aka. the **receiver object**) **inside** the method (before aka. mind blowing) by creating it itself, but only defines the "function types with receiver" in the signature of the method. By calling `transaction.functionName`, it assigns `transaction` as `this` inside `functionName`. Now callers of `fragmentManager.commit {}` can comfortably (not me ) configure a transaction without even creating it.

---

Among other confusion, I was also confused as to how the method (`commit`) gets the "receiver type" (`FragmentTransaction`). It came from **inside** the function!